#  How to print previous and next lines to compare strings when reading line by line

Tags: java

I am reading a csv file line by line and I am trying to compare previous, current and next  lines. I know I need to save three string variables as I am reading a line. But I am stuck as to how to save my three variables so that when I read line 4 to be able to print line 3 and line 5.

Comment: Looks suspiciously like a post at Java-Forums that was already answered with the same answer as glowcoder but days ago: [how-read-current-previous-next-line-text-file](http://www.java-forums.org/advanced-java/42817-how-read-current-previous-next-line-text-file.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String prev = null;
String curr = null;
String next = null;

Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("thefile.csv"));

while(sc.hasNextLine()) {
    prev = curr;
    curr = next;
    next = sc.nextLine();

    // now process those lines

}
```

Comment: glowcoder - you are a life saver, you make it look very simple. thank you!

Comment: @corsiKa  If I wanted to work with the current element (curr) in the first pass I'll get a null pointer exception. Is there a workaround for it?

Comment: @serendipity Yeah, let me just remember where I left off 6 years ago. Okay, got it. Declare the scanner FIRST, then the strings. Make prev and curr null, and next sc.nextLine. Note that this will cause you to skip your last element, so you have to do your logic after the loop is over too. But you'll find that during debugging.

Answer (score 1):

Save them in an array. Then use -1 and +1 relative to the index number while looping through. Don't forget to check if -1 and +1 actually exist, and catch exceptions just in case.

Comment: If the input gets very large, you're going to end up with a lot of memory consumed for something that should have a constant memory.

Comment: glowcoder's solution is better if you don't need to store the input. His solution is more efficient because it only does one pass. Mine would require 2 and more memory.

Comment: Though if the input file is small, an ArrayList (rather than an array), could work just fine.